# Are there templating systems that allow you to edit HTML, CSS and Javascript in the same file?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web-frameworks, templating

When you have a small HTML template, wouldn't it be nice to have the CSS and Javascript that relate to it (binding of events, etc.) in the same file right next to the HTML?

You could just put them in  and  tags, but normally you don't want to do this, because when you render the template many times you'll end up multiplying the code over and over again in the DOM. Besides, every respecting webdeveloper wants their CSS and Javasciprt in separate files.

But it's actually pretty simple to implement a system that goes through all your templates, removes all the  tags with their contents and puts them into one big .css file and then the  with contents to .js file, so that you can load them from separate files, and finally the tempalates are left with only HTML in them.

I'v done this and i'm still learning with the best practices on how to use it (eg. what parts of Javasript do you want to put there?), but it feels like the way i'd always want to develop web apps. So i'm wondering if there are any systems that use the same method.

Comment: I'm having a bit of a hard time locating and/or understanding the question. Are you talking about Javascript templates? Are you using some kind of server side language? If so, which one?

Comment: I'm using Javascript templates. But i'm sure the same could be done also for server side templates (though there might be slight performance hit if you want to remove the <stylesheet> and <script> tags dynamically).

Answer (score 0):

Parsing HTML to remove duplicate tags as a standard practice seems wrong. Separating content, style and behavior should be a first class priority in any case. Why combine something just to rip it apart again? Imagine your CSS differs slightly among files. How does your parser know which one to keep?

IMO a proper templating approach for Javascript has a main HTML file, which is loaded using a HTTP request, which again links the CSS and JS for the rest of the application. This first file can as well link JS template files (like e.g. .jst) or these are loaded later on demand using an AJAX request. Nevertheless are these templates usually only containing structure, content comes from e.g. a JS model using a JSON connection to some kind of storage, "styling" is provided by the previously loaded CSS files.

*Related: [backbone.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/) and [sammy.js](http://sammyjs.org/)*

Comment: Why do this? Because of the work performance gain you get by not having to jump around three different files when working. How does CSS know which rule to obay? The way it normally does, based on the strength of CSS rules you give it (eg. ".top_class .sub_class" over ".sub_class"). Sure, there are lot's of Javascript that you don't want to put in templates and lot's of CSS that affects many templates. Keep them in separate files! But there's also a lot, that only affects single templates.

Comment: To clarify, CSS and Javascipt is separeted from the templates already on the server side. So the Javascript templates (however you want to load them) only have HTML.

Comment: It's a question of maintainability as well. You can handle your code however you please (you did ask the question, though ;) ), but you will notice that there has been a strong trend through–out the history of web development towards separation and DRY structures (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself). And for good reasons. I recommend to build a larger application the way you're suggesting and to collaborate with others while doing so. Given that I didn't misunderstand you, I'd assume that you will encounter certain difficulties related to your approach along the way.

Comment: I am building a relatively big JS application (three developers full time on the front end). And i don't see how this conflicts with the DRY principle. The idea is to put only the code that relates to that template in it, and so far i haven't seen and repetition coming from it.

Comment: But you're saying that you'd be placing whatever JS and CSS is needed for each fragment within the fragment (or template), then take everything apart and store it in separate files programatically, right? And if JS library or class XY has been included in fragment 1 and fragment 2, it will appear naturally only once in the end result?

Comment: Yes, but if by including JS library you mean appending its <script> tag to DOM (for loading), that's something i wouldn't do in a template file. The idea is to put there stuff that is only used within that template (for example binding events to buttons). Things that affect many templates should be put somewhere else.

Comment: Alright, now I'm starting to see your reasons a bit better. I had understood that you want to include the dependencies as well. I'm still not fully in for the idea, but I can see how this is much more of a matter of taste. Enjoying the discussion, though ;) .